# Invoke process in windows by another user using primary token using JNA

Tags: java, windows, jna, advapi32

I need to invoke windows process by another user with primary token, using jna (java).
I am able to peform:

1. Login with username, domain & password
2. Duplicate token, to generate primary token with dwDesiredAccess set to 33554432 . I'm not sure on the value, this may be the culprit here. Please guide what's the correct value for this. I need to give MAXIMUM_ALLOWED permission, not sure what's equivalent for that in terms of java Integer
3. Invoking some random windows command.

On step 3, i'm getting issue that `A required privilege is not held by the client`. I have tried different ways, OpenThreadToken and AdjustTokenPrivilege, but that didn't work for me.

Can someone please guide me on how to invoke a process using jna with below code.

Note: I need to invoke multiple commands thus, need to use primary token way.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     HANDLE loginToken = null;
     HANDLE primaryToken = null; 
    try {
         loginToken = performLogin("username", "domain", "password"); 
        setThreadToken(loginToken); 
        primaryToken = createPrimaryToken(loginToken, 33554432);
         invokeCommand(primaryToken);
     } catch (ProcessCreationException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
     } finally {
         if (loginToken != null)
             Kernel32.INSTANCE.CloseHandle(loginToken);
         if (primaryToken != null) 
            Kernel32.INSTANCE.CloseHandle(primaryToken); 
    }
 }


private static HANDLE performLogin(String username, String domain, String password) throws ProcessCreationException { 
   HANDLEByReference pointer = new HANDLEByReference(); 
   invokeWindowsMethod("login", () -> Advapi32.INSTANCE.LogonUser(username, domain,  password, WinBase.LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, WinBase.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, pointer)); 
    return pointer.getValue(); 
}


private static HANDLE createPrimaryToken(HANDLE loginToken, int desiredAccess) throws ProcessCreationException {
     System.out.println("dwDesiredAccess:" + desiredAccess);
     HANDLEByReference pointer = new HANDLEByReference();
     invokeWindowsMethod("duplicated", () -> Advapi32.INSTANCE.DuplicateTokenEx(
             loginToken, 
            desiredAccess,
             null,
             SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityDelegation,
             TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary,
             pointer
     ));
     return pointer.getValue(); 
}

private static void invokeCommand(HANDLE primaryToken) throws ProcessCreationException {
     STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
     PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION(); 
    pi.clear();  
    invokeWindowsMethod("invokeCommand", () -> Advapi32.INSTANCE.CreateProcessAsUser(
             primaryToken,
            null,
             "whoami",
             null, 
            null, 
            true, 
            1024,
             null,
             null, 
            si,
             pi));
 }


private static void invokeWindowsMethod(String method, Supplier<Boolean> processor) throws ProcessCreationException { 
    Boolean res = processor.get(); 
    System.out.println(method + " : " + res); 
    if (!res) { 
        throw lastErrorProcessCreationException(method, Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError());
     } 
}


private static ProcessCreationException lastErrorProcessCreationException(String context, int errorCode) { 
    return new ProcessCreationException(String.format("[%s] %s", context,  Kernel32Util.formatMessageFromLastErrorCode(errorCode)));
 }
```

Comment: Where did 33554432 come from?

Comment: I tried to extract the value of this constant from c++ code, but this doesn’t seem to work for me.

Comment: It doesn't work because it's not relevant to the particular command you are using. The WinAPI is well documented on what you need to use.

Answer (score 0):

You are

> Invoking some random windows command.

And you need

> A required privilege is not held by the client

The Windows API generally tells you what privileges each command needs.

I assume you found the value 33554432 in someone's code somewhere.  It's generally more readable if you use the appropriate constant corresponding to its meaning.  A decimal to hex converter tells me that's 0x2000000 which is [WSManFlagSkipRevocationCheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/authentication-constants).  Define that constant and use it in your code ... if indeed that's the one you need.  But what you really need is shown by the docs for the command you are running:

The "Random Command" you chose is [`CreateProcessAsUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasuserw) which tells you exactly how to handle this error:

> Typically, the process that calls the **CreateProcessAsUser** function must have the **SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME** privilege and may require the **SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME** privilege if the token is not assignable.

So your calling process doesn't have the right privileges. You need to enable those.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64195567/why-does-kernel32-openprocess-function-return-null/64196851#64196851) for how to enable a privelege on the current process using Java/JNA code (change the `SE_DEBUG_NAME` to the privilege you are requesting).

Further, the `CreateProcessAsUser` docs continue:

> If this function fails with **ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD** (1314), use the **CreateProcessWithLogonW** function instead. [CreateProcessWithLogonW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithlogonw) requires no special privileges, but the specified user account must be allowed to log on interactively. Generally, it is best to use **CreateProcessWithLogonW** to create a process with alternate credentials.

Requiring no special privilege seems a better option for you to use than a "Random windows command" that needs other steps.

Comment: How to add MAXIMUM_ALLOWED privilege using JNA ?

Comment: Can you provide the code if possible please.

Comment: I already linked to another answer of mine with complete code on how to add a privilege. Just replace the particular privilege I added (SE_DEBUG_NAME) with the one you want.  I already stated this in my answer.